# PHP замена html кода

Tags: php

у меня такая проблема:
Мне нужно что бы когда пользователь авторизовывался через стим, то надпись "Войти через стим" менялась на ник игрока, а также у меня по дефолту стоит аватарка, но при авторизации она менялась на аву игрока, и как мне это сделать?

PHP:

```
include('include/db.php');
include('include/steamauth/steamauth.php');

if(isset($_SESSION['steamid'])){
    require 'include/steamauth/userInfo.php'; // подключение инфо о игроке
    $nickname = $steamprofile['personaname'];
    $ava = $steamprofile['avatar'],
}
```

HTML:

```
//Avatar
<div class="login-header__ava">
    <img src="./image/header/ava.jpg" alt ="" width="60"height="60">
</div>

//Вход
<div class="login-header__singup">
    <a href="?login">Войти через Steam</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас тут проверяется подключение к стиму:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['steamid'])){
    require 'include/steamauth/userInfo.php'; // подключение инфо о игроке
    $nickname = $steamprofile['personaname'];
    $ava = $steamprofile['avatar'],
}
```

Следовательно можно зделать так:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['steamid'])){
    require 'include/steamauth/userInfo.php'; // подключение инфо о игроке
    $nickname = '<div class="login-header__singup">
                   <div>'. $steamprofile["personaname"] .'</div>
                   </div>';

    $ava = '<div class="login-header__ava">
              <img src="'. $steamprofile["avatar"] .'" alt ="" width="60"height="60">
            </div>';
}
else {
    $nickname = '<div class="login-header__singup">
                    <a href="?login">Войти через Steam</a>
                </div>';

    $ava = '<div class="login-header__ava">
               <img src="./image/header/ava.jpg" alt ="" width="60"height="60">
            </div>';
}
```

Тогда в шаблоне просто вставляете переменные `$nickname` и `$ava`. В таком случае у вас в html будет минимум php кода.

Можно оставить все как есть и в шаблоне проверять сущесвуют ли переменные `$nickname` и `$ava` и соответственно вы водить нужный html. Тогда в шаблоне будет больше php кода. Выберать вам.